# Spring Boot share code across different projects

Tags: spring-boot, module, microservices

I've been reading a lot about micro-services and modules but still I can not figure out how can I achieve this scenario.

I've got many Spring Boot projects and almost all of them having the same features like:

- Login and Registration
- Email for password reset
- Email for account confirmation
- JWT Access
- Web UI

Even the database structure of those features is identical across them.

I imagine there must be a way to take it out from the app and re-use it in every project, instead of duplicating it on every project.

I was also thinking in having it on a separate repo.

Can please someone point me in the right direction?

Right now what I'm doing is: I have a base (boiler-plate) Spring Boot project and use it as starting point of any app. The problem is that whenever I add a new feature or fix a bug on the boiler-plate I need to "*cascade*" those changes to every project using it

Thank you!

Comment: user management could be a service for itself? Or you could share a library as maven or gradle dependency?

Comment: Hello sschrass! You are suggesting me to make user managment as an independent service? About the library, can I access DB from it? If you could explain yourself a bit more or maybe some minimal example about project structure would be nice. thanks!